# Go slices mutation best practices

Tags: go, slice

It's not very predictable to know whether the underlying original array is getting mutated or whether its the copy of the original array that is getting mutated when slices are passed around

```
a = [3]int {0, 1, 2}
s = a[:]
s[0] = 10
a[0] == s[0] // true


s = append(s, 3)
s[0] = 20
a[0] == s[0] // false
```

Let' say today I had a processing of this kind

```
a = [3]int {0, 1, 2}
s = some_func(a[:]) // returns slice
process(s) // a is getting mutated because so far some_func hasn't caused the underlying array to be copied
```

and now tomorrow

```
a = [3]int {0, 1, 2}
s = some_func(a[:]) // returns slice, does append operations
process(s) // a is not getting mutated because some_func caused the underlying array to be copied
```

What are the best practices for slices then?

Comment: "It's not very predictable to know whether the underlying original array is getting mutated or whether its the copy of the original array that is getting mutated when slices are passed around" - what about it is unpredictable exactly? What specifically are you finding confusing?

Comment: maybe i can be totally wrong about the usage of slice, but given a slice, mutation happens on the original array until the array gets copied. Once its capacity is reached, the original array doesn't get mutated. wouldn't that be confusing? @Adrian

Comment: The function's documentation should specify what it does with its arguments if it is of any relevance to the caller. What it does not specify is basically undefined behavior and the caller should not rely on behavior that is undefined.

Comment: `append` returns a slice because it might append to the same slice or it might have to allocate a new slice if there is not sufficient capacity. That is how append works, and therefore how you should assume it will behave - that it might return the same slice or a new slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function really does modify a slice's underlying array in place, and *promises* that it *always* modifies the underlying array in place, that function should in general take the slice argument by value and not return an updated slice:<sup>1</sup>

```
// Mutate() modifies (the backing array of) s in place to achieve $result.
// See below for why it returns an int.
func Mutate(s []T) int {
    // code
}
```

If a function *may* modify the underlying array in place but *may* return a slice that uses a new array, the function should return a new slice value, or take a pointer to a slice:

```
// Replace() operates on a slice of T, but may return a totally new
// slice of T.
func Replace(s []T) []T {
    // code
}
```

When this function returns, you should assume that the underlying array, if you have hold of it, may or may not be in use:

```
func callsReplace() {
    var arr [10]T
    s := Replace(arr[:])
    // From here on, do not use variable arr directly as
    // we don't know if it is s's backing array, or not.

    // more code
}
```

But `Mutate()` promises to modify the array in place.  Note that `Mutate` will often need to return the number of array elements actually updated:

```
func callsMutate() {
    var arr [10]T
    n := Mutate(arr[:])
    // now work with arr[0] through arr[n]

    // more code
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, it could take a pointer to the array object, and modify the array in place, but that's less flexible since the array size is then baked in to the type.